# Css is overriding / Image Rotation in css JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image

I want to create image Editor with functionality of Image Rotation, Image Color Changer (Sepia/Gray) and Price Calculator on Height and Width. 
Also I want to add Image Selector(Image Crop) in this editor.

Can Anyone help me to correct this code.

img css is overriding in this code when I click on Rotate button it rotates image but also when I click on color button it changes color as well rotates image.. I dont know how to remove this overriding or use something else.

Also need help to rotate image in particular div.

```js
$('input[name="color"]').on('change', function() {
  $('div.imageDiv')
    .removeClass('original sepia gray')
    .addClass($(this).val());
});

function calculate() {
  var myBox1 = document.getElementById('box1').value;
  var myBox2 = document.getElementById('box2').value;
  var result = document.getElementById('result');
  var myResult = [(myBox1 * myBox2 * 0.69) / 100];
  result.value = myResult;
}

$('input').click(function() {
  var img = $('img');
  if (img.hasClass('north')) {
    img.attr('class', 'west');
  } else if (img.hasClass('west')) {
    img.attr('class', 'south');
  } else if (img.hasClass('south')) {
    img.attr('class', 'east');
  } else if (img.hasClass('east')) {
    img.attr('class', 'north');
  }
});
```

```css
img {
  display: block;
  width: 50%;
}
.original {} .sepia {
  -webkit-filter: sepia(1);
  filter: sepia(1);
}
.gray {
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(1);
  filter: grayscale(1);
}
.north {
  transform: rotate(0deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
  /* IE 9 */
  -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  /* Safari and Chrome */
}
.west {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
  /* IE 9 */
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
  /* Safari and Chrome */
}
.south {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(180deg);
  /* IE 9 */
  -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
  /* Safari and Chrome */
}
.east {
  transform: rotate(270deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(270deg);
  /* IE 9 */
  -webkit-transform: rotate(270deg);
  /* Safari and Chrome */
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" checked="checked" value="original" name="color" />Color
<br />
<input type="radio" value="gray" name="color" />Gray
<br />
<input type="radio" value="sepia" name="color" />Sepia</p>
<div class="imageDiv original">
  <img class="north" alt="" src="https://blog.stackexchange.com/images/wordpress/stackoverflow-logo-alt2-300.png" />
</div>
<br>
<br>
<input type="button" value="Rotate">
<table border="0">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>Length in cm</th>
      <th>Width in cm</th>
      <th>Total Price in A$</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input id="box1" type="text" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input id="box2" type="text" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input id="result" type="text" />
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<p>
```

Comment: Can you correct it and help me to add image selector..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You added the click event to all the input tags due to which when the radio button is clicked it will rotate the image so I add input[name="color"] so that the click event does start when radio button is clicked and Rotate is worked when button is clicked which name is "rotate"

```html
$('input[name="rotate"]').click(function(){
    var img = $('img');
    if(img.hasClass('north')){
        img.attr('class','west');
    }else if(img.hasClass('west')){
        img.attr('class','south');
    }else if(img.hasClass('south')){
        img.attr('class','east');
    }else if(img.hasClass('east')){
        img.attr('class','north');
    }
}); 


 $('input[name="color"]').on('change', function () {
  $('div.imageDiv')
        .removeClass('original sepia gray')
        .addClass($(this).val());
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the http://jsfiddle.net/kt4c2jca/ it contains the correct code. 
you need to update the last function to

```
$('input[!name="color"]').click(function () {
    var img = $('img');
    if (img.hasClass('north')) {
        img.attr('class', 'west');
    } else if (img.hasClass('west')) {
        img.attr('class', 'south');
    } else if (img.hasClass('south')) {
        img.attr('class', 'east');
    } else if (img.hasClass('east')) {
        img.attr('class', 'north');
    }
});
```

check out the js fiddle to see it working.

you added the click event to all the `input` tags due to which when the radio button is clicked it will rotate the image so I added `input[!name="color"]` so that the click event does not start when radio button is clicked

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in binding events. You are binding two events:

```
$('input[name="color"]').on('change', function() {
  //color chnage code
});

$('input').click(function() {
  //Rotation code
});
```

You are binding "CLICK" event with all inputs and "CHANGE" event with only color check-boxes.

So when you click color check-box then both function will call that's why you are facing issue.

**SOLUTION-1:** Give an "ID" to the rotate button and then bind "CLICK" event.

```
$('input[name="color"]').on('change', function() {
  //color chnage code
});

$('#id_of_rotate_button').click(function() {
  //Rotation code
});
```

**SOLUTION-2:**  Bind "CLICK" event to button

```
$('input[name="color"]').on('change', function() {
  //color chnage code
});

$('input:button').click(function() {
  //Rotation code
});
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32201650/how-to-get-cropped-image-with-gray-sepia-in-my-editor  Can you help in that..

Answer (score 0):

It's not an override — you're binding the 'rotation' handler to `$('input')`, which is *every input in the page*, including the 'color' button.

Change it to a more specific selector like you did for the 'color' one and it should work better.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32201650/how-to-get-cropped-image-with-gray-sepia-in-my-editor  Can you help in that..