# How to get cropped image with gray/ sepia in my editor.?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hi I am creating a image editor where on radio button check it changes image color into gray and sepia .. and I want to cropped image on that color(gray/sepia)

When I click on Gray it should return that color image when i click on Get Cropped Canvas.

Below is the my code. Some css and js file are not included. you can see live example here [Click here for demo](http://demo.lifestylewallart.com.au/imageedit/demo/index.html)

Please let me know how can I get cropped image on that color which radio button is selected Check this image https://i.stack.imgur.com/TkwHm.jpg

```js
$(function () {

  'use strict';

  var console = window.console || { log: function () {} };
  var $body = $('body');

  $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
  $.fn.tooltip.noConflict();
  $body.tooltip();

  // Demo
  // -------------------------------------------------------------------------

  (function () {
    var $image = $('.img-container > img');
    var $dataX = $('#dataX');
    var $dataY = $('#dataY');
    var $dataHeight = $('#dataHeight');
    var $dataWidth = $('#dataWidth');
    var $dataRotate = $('#dataRotate');
    var $dataScaleX = $('#dataScaleX');
    var $dataScaleY = $('#dataScaleY');
    var options = {
          aspectRatio: 16 / 9,
          preview: '.img-preview',
          crop: function (e) {
            $dataX.val(Math.round(e.x));
            $dataY.val(Math.round(e.y));
            $dataHeight.val(Math.round(e.height));
            $dataWidth.val(Math.round(e.width));
            $dataRotate.val(e.rotate);
            $dataScaleX.val(e.scaleX);
            $dataScaleY.val(e.scaleY);
          }
        };

    $image.on({
      'build.cropper': function (e) {
        console.log(e.type);
      },
      'built.cropper': function (e) {
        console.log(e.type);
      },
      'cropstart.cropper': function (e) {
        console.log(e.type, e.action);
      },
      'cropmove.cropper': function (e) {
        console.log(e.type, e.action);
      },
      'cropend.cropper': function (e) {
        console.log(e.type, e.action);
      },
      'crop.cropper': function (e) {
        console.log(e.type, e.x, e.y, e.width, e.height, e.rotate, e.scaleX, e.scaleY);
      },
      'zoom.cropper': function (e) {
        console.log(e.type, e.ratio);
      }
    }).cropper(options);


    // Methods
    $body.on('click', '[data-method]', function () {
      var data = $(this).data();
      var $target;
      var result;

      if (!$image.data('cropper')) {
        return;
      }

      if (data.method) {
        data = $.extend({}, data); // Clone a new one

        if (typeof data.target !== 'undefined') {
          $target = $(data.target);

          if (typeof data.option === 'undefined') {
            try {
              data.option = JSON.parse($target.val());
            } catch (e) {
              console.log(e.message);
            }
          }
        }

        result = $image.cropper(data.method, data.option, data.secondOption);

        if (data.flip === 'horizontal') {
          $(this).data('option', -data.option);
        }

        if (data.flip === 'vertical') {
          $(this).data('secondOption', -data.secondOption);
        }

        if (data.method === 'getCroppedCanvas') {
         
          $('#getCroppedCanvasModal').modal().find('.modal-body').html(result);
           

        if ($.isPlainObject(result) && $target) {
          try {
            $target.val(JSON.stringify(result));
          } catch (e) {
            console.log(e.message);
          }
        }

      }
    }).on('keydown', function (e) {

      if (!$image.data('cropper')) {
        return;
      }

      switch (e.which) {
        case 37:
          e.preventDefault();
          $image.cropper('move', -1, 0);
          break;

        case 38:
          e.preventDefault();
          $image.cropper('move', 0, -1);
          break;

        case 39:
          e.preventDefault();
          $image.cropper('move', 1, 0);
          break;

        case 40:
          e.preventDefault();
          $image.cropper('move', 0, 1);
          break;
      }

    });


    // Import image
    var $inputImage = $('#inputImage');
    var URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
    var blobURL;

    if (URL) {
      $inputImage.change(function () {
        var files = this.files;
        var file;

        if (!$image.data('cropper')) {
          return;
        }

        if (files && files.length) {
          file = files[0];

          if (/^image\/\w+$/.test(file.type)) {
            blobURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);
            $image.one('built.cropper', function () {
              URL.revokeObjectURL(blobURL); // Revoke when load complete
            }).cropper('reset').cropper('replace', blobURL);
            $inputImage.val('');
          } else {
            $body.tooltip('Please choose an image file.', 'warning');
          }
        }
      });
    } else {
      $inputImage.parent().remove();
    }


    // Options
    $('.docs-options :checkbox').on('change', function () {
      var $this = $(this);
      var cropBoxData;
      var canvasData;

      if (!$image.data('cropper')) {
        return;
      }

      options[$this.val()] = $this.prop('checked');

      cropBoxData = $image.cropper('getCropBoxData');
      canvasData = $image.cropper('getCanvasData');
      options.built = function () {
        $image.cropper('setCropBoxData', cropBoxData);
        $image.cropper('setCanvasData', canvasData);
      };

      $image.cropper('destroy').cropper(options);
    });

  }());

});


 $('input[name="color"]').on('change', function () {
 $('div.imageDiv')
  .removeClass('original sepia gray')
         .addClass($(this).val());
        $('div.img-preview')
         .removeClass('original sepia gray')
         .addClass($(this).val());
        
         
});
```

```css
@media (max-width: 400px) {
  .btn-group-crop {
    margin-right: -15px!important;
  }

  .btn-group-crop > .btn {
    padding-left: 5px;
    padding-right: 5px;
  }

  .btn-group-crop .docs-tooltip {
    margin-left: -5px;
    margin-right: -5px;
    padding-left: 5px;
    padding-right: 5px;
  }
}

.original { }
 .sepia {
     -webkit-filter: sepia(1);
     filter: sepia(1);
 }
 .gray {
     -webkit-filter: grayscale(1);
     filter: grayscale(1);
 }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../assets/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../assets/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../assets/css/tooltip.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../dist/cropper.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">

<div class="btn-group">
        <button type="button"  class="btn btn-primary" title="Color"> <input type="radio" checked="checked" value="original" name="color" />Color</button> 
        <button type="button"  class="btn btn-primary" title="Gray"> <input type="radio" value="gray" name="color" />Gray</button> 
        <button type="button"  class="btn btn-primary" title="Sepia"> <input type="radio" value="sepia" name="color" />Sepia</button>
        </div>

        <div class="btn-group btn-group-crop">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-method="getCroppedCanvas">
            <span class="docs-tooltip" data-toggle="tooltip" title="$().cropper(&quot;getCroppedCanvas&quot;)">
              Get Cropped Canvas
            </span>
          </button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-method="getCroppedCanvas" data-option="{ &quot;width&quot;: 160, &quot;height&quot;: 90 }">
            <span class="docs-tooltip" data-toggle="tooltip" title="$().cropper(&quot;getCroppedCanvas&quot;, { width: 160, height: 90 })">
              160&times;90
            </span>
          </button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-method="getCroppedCanvas" data-option="{ &quot;width&quot;: 320, &quot;height&quot;: 180 }">
            <span class="docs-tooltip" data-toggle="tooltip" title="$().cropper(&quot;getCroppedCanvas&quot;, { width: 320, height: 180 })">
              320&times;180
            </span>
          </button>
        </div>

        <!-- Show the cropped image in modal -->
        <div class="modal fade docs-cropped" id="getCroppedCanvasModal" aria-hidden="true" aria-labelledby="getCroppedCanvasTitle" role="dialog" tabindex="-1">
          <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
              <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="getCroppedCanvasTitle">Cropped</h4>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-body"></div>
              <!-- <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
              </div> -->
            </div>
          </div>
        </div><!-- /.modal -->

 <!-- Scripts -->
  <script src="../assets/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="../assets/js/tooltip.min.js"></script>
  <script src="../assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="../dist/cropper.js"></script>
  <script src="js/main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: How do you import image in your editor? I have tried with 'Import image with BLOB URLs' but it's not working for me. I also got `SyntaxError: expected expression, got ')'` error in console when loading page, using FF v40.0.2.

Comment: @ Ivan Jovovic its working fine in my side . try to refresh page..

Comment: Now it works :) Have you tried just to apply `css` class to `modal-body` class: `var colorClass = $("input:radio[name=color]:checked").val();
         $('#getCroppedCanvasModal').modal().find('.modal-body').removeClass('original sepia gray').addClass(colorClass).html(result);` ?

Comment: Thanks .. It works ...

Comment: Great. I have posted this as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to apply css class to `modal-body` class inside `$body.on('click', '[data-method]', function () {`:

```
var colorClass = $("input:radio[name=color]:checked").val();
$('#getCroppedCanvasModal').modal().find('.modal-body').
removeClass('original sepia gray').addClass(colorClass).html(result);
```

Comment: I need a little help in that editor. When user add height and width in right boxes the crop canvas  should selected to that size and disable to resize it  then.. user must again update height and width.  Check live example here http://lifestylewallart.com.au/imageeditor/index.html

Comment: Ivan Jovovic .. can you help with this...I need a little help in that editor. When user add height and width in right boxes the crop canvas should selected to that size and disable to resize it then.. user must again update height and width. Check live example here lifestylewallart.com.au/imageeditor/index.php